# jquery is not working in jsp when the page is loaded via requestdispatcher.forward

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am working with servlets.I have created a jsp page and it includes some scripts for jquery.Every statements using jquery is working fine when the page is loaded from servlet using response.sendredirect(). as below

```
response.sendRedirect("./ff/test.jsp");
```

I have done the same thing by using requestdispatcher.forward() because i need to pass a data to that jsp.

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("./ff/test.jsp");
     rd.forward(request, response);
```

Now it has redirected to correct jsp page and also the data can be accessed inside that page.But the problem is that I am getting reference error "$ is not defined".Is it possible to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you writing anything else to the response that's causing this wrong behavior?

Comment: no.I didn't add more statements

Comment: Your case is strange. You have something else that's blocking or deactivating your javascript/jquery and it's not posted here. Provide the necessary elements to replicate the problem: necessary code in servlet, in JSP, etc., otherwise your question is unclear.

Comment: using firebug or similiar, are there any html/js errors?

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your jsp.

Comment: Please use 'view source' of the browser and check that the jQuery js path is correct.

Comment: I think jquery.js path is correct that's why it is working fine in response.sendredirect

Comment: @ScaryWombat  firebug shows the error $ is not defined

Comment: please post your jquery code or what kind of operations you are trying to do with jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript links should be like `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/yourpath/yourfilename.js></script>`.  This is just an example.  You must specify request.getContextPath() because your context is now the context of the servlet not the jsp so relative path won't work here.